# Very close triangle centers X360 and X176

Tags: geometry, triangles

Friend of mine saw very interesting triangle centers which are closely located for any triangle. 
Those are Hofstadter point D (X360: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_points) and the Outer Soddy center E (X176: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OuterSoddyCenter.html).

[image]

The question I have a bit out of scope may be: But can this cause any fundamental physical law or some formula in discrete mathematics? In other words I would like to ask about the applications of this.

EDITED:

And even more if we consider the line connecting Hofstadter 0 and 1 points (X359 and X360) the X176 is located amazingly close to this line. The maximum distance I was able to get is less than 0.05 for triangle with area grater than 15000.

[image]

Comment: Please just pay an attention that X360 is a transcendental point while X176 is not.

Comment: As the [Encyclopedia of Triangle centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) lists **15423** different centers, it is not a surprise if two of them happen to lie one near to the other.

Comment: I agree. But those two are extremely close. And those are interesting because of one is transcendental and another is not. For example for the triangle with area 205 the maximum distance I was able to find is 0.47.

Comment: The Geogebra has a special function trianglecenter(A,B,C,<point number>).